Ghost AI not moving through intersections (Phaser 3, PacMan)
I am trying to make a pac_man game with Phaser 3. I have implemented the pac_man movement, however, I really need help with the ghost AI. The ghost is moving by its self, however, it is not passing through any intersections. Like, it only moves in a different direction when it collides with something else. I am trying to fix this, and yet I don't know how. I am using physics, with arcade. Here is some of the code:
newDirections(sprite) {
        let directions = ['left', 'right', 'down', 'up']
        return directions.filter(d => !sprite.body.blocked[d]);
}

This function is supposed to see any other paths the ghost can take. I am highly depended on sprite.body.blocked for this (especially since I am using tiles), but it only reads when the sprite is colliding with something else.
The problem is, the sprite.body.blocked only returns the accurate dictionary of of blocked areas on a sprite when the sprite is colliding with something. Otherwise, it only returns {none: true, up: false, down: false, left: false, right: false}. Because of this, the ghost, 'sprite' only moves when it collides with something. Thus, it doesn't pass through any intersections.
So basically, I want something that will actively say whether or not it is blocked (touching) by an object or not, not only when it is colliding with an object.
I heavily appreciate any help or advice you'd give.

This is a comment, not an answer: in JS, Array indices start at 0, not 1. You need to change let i = 1;

Hello! That was done on purpose. I wanted to leave out the first index in the array.

In this case, this would probably make more sense : return directions.filter(d => !sprite.body.blocked[d]);. Other than that, I'm not sure I understand what is wrong with it. The logic in your code seems to be ok. Could you be more precise about what is not working? Maybe the problem lays somewhere else in the game?

Thanks for the headsup. I have edited my post.

Well it depends on how you are moving the ghost, but an option would be to add a collider, that checks for overlaps (this.physics.add.overlap(...)) and just querying the tiles around of the current tile the ghost is on (layer.getTileAt(...)), if movement is possible.
Short Demo (Updated):
(ShowCasing movement, just demo code will need tweaking)
Update Demo incorporates the random new direction selection, with special intersection tiles
Letters in SquareBrackes show possible direction change options.


const speed = 10;

// Map with only 2 Tiles
// 1 ... wall
// 0 ... walkable tiles
// 2 ... walkable tile, invisible marker to turn
const level = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];

// demo helper variables
// needs to be improved
let lastDirection = 'down';

// quickfix
// prevent double direction switch
let lastTile;

class DemoScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  create() {
    this.createDemoAssets();
    this.info = this.add.text(2, 2, '[]').setOrigin(0).setDepth(100).setSize(1);

    const map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 8, tileHeight: 8, width: 10, height: 8 });
    map.setCollision([1]);
    const tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tiles', 'tiles', 8, 8);
    const layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);

    let ghost = this.physics.add.sprite(12, 12, 'ghost').setOrigin(0.5); // set Sprite Origin to center

    ghost.setVelocityY(speed);

    // bind ghost to scene
    this.ghost = ghost;

    console.info(ghost.body.velocity.y * -1);
    this.physics.add.collider(ghost, layer);
    this.physics.add.overlap(ghost, layer, (ghost, tile) => {
      // quick fix double direction switch
      if (lastTile == tile) {
        return;
      }
      //reset label
      this.info.setText(`[]`);

      // only check on special intersection tiles
      if (tile.index == 2) {
        
        let directions = [
          { x: 0, y: -1, name: 'up' },
          { x: 1, y: 0, name: 'right' },
          { x: 0, y: 1, name: 'down' },
          { x: -1, y: 0, name: 'left' },
        ]
          // selects all nodes that are "walkable" "index == 0"
          .filter((node) => {
            return layer.getTileAt(tile.x + node.x, tile.y + node.y).index == 0;
          })
          // creates a new array, with only the name
          .map((x) => x.name);

        console.info(directions);
        this.info.setText(`[${directions.map((x) => x[0]).join(',')}]`);

        // +4 is half tile width == middle of the tile (quickfix for demo)
        if (Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(tile.pixelX + 4, tile.pixelY + 4, ghost.x, ghost.y) < 1) {
           lastTile = tile;
          // select new direction an set speed
          this.setGhostdirection(directions);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // from here helper functions for demo, should be improved/removed
  createDemoAssets() {
    let graphics = this.make.graphics();

    // tilesheet
    graphics.fillStyle(0xcdcdcd);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0x7a7a7a);
    graphics.fillRect(8, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    graphics.fillRect(16, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.generateTexture(`tiles`, 24, 8);

    //ghost
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.generateTexture(`ghost`, 5, 5);
  }

  setGhostdirection(options) {
    // don't turn 180 degrees
    let goodOptions = options.filter((option) => option != lastDirection);

    let selectedOption = Phaser.Math.RND.pick(goodOptions);

    console.info(selectedOption);
    // set lastDirection
    lastDirection = selectedOption;
    // ghost speed
    switch (selectedOption) {
      case 'down':
        this.ghost.setVelocity(0, speed);
        break;
      case 'up':
        this.ghost.setVelocity(0, -speed);
        break;

      case 'left':
        this.ghost.setVelocity(-speed, 0);
        break;
      case 'right':
        this.ghost.setVelocity(speed, 0);
        break;
    }
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 10 * 8,
  height: 8 * 8,
  zoom: 4,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
  },
  scene: DemoScene,
};

new Phaser.Game(config);

console.clear();
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>




Info: This is just demo code, it has a few quick fixes, just to make it run smooth for the demo (and to keep the code short), should be improved/optimized for "production".


Hey! Thanks a lot for the help. I have transferred the code onto mine, but for some reason, the 'direction' list is always returning an empty set '[]'. Are you aware of the fact that return layer.getTileAt(tile.x + node.x, tile.y + node.y).index == 0; returns a boolean?

Also, the indexes never equal 0. They always equal -1 or 139 for some reason.

Well yes I know it returns a boolean. its a filter expression and must return a boolean (link to doc). It works for this script, because my "movable tile" has the index 0 you would have to adjust it for your code, if your player can move on other tiles other than those with the "index == 0". Did you run my demo? You can run it in the browser.

p.s.: I added some comments in the code to make it more clear.

depending on you movement scenario and game, you to have invisible collision points on the intersections ( as a Navigation helper ) and than using them to decide to turn or not. (would also be better for performance)

Ok, I'll try that. Thanks.

Update my answer showcasing the direction swap with the special tiles. I hope it helps, if so please consider upvoting or accepting my answer. Thank you .
